# Update date on click without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I wrote this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#updateAssignment').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var currentdate = new Date();
  var datetime = "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                + (currentdate.getMonth())  + "/"
                + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":"
                + currentdate.getSeconds();
  $('#updateAssignment').text(datetime);
});
</script>
```

With this html:

```
<p class="card-text" id="updateAssignment">Last update: <?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s')?> <a href="?update=true"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a></p>
```

What I want is the following:

I want the date to update when I click on the refresh button **without the complete page to refresh**. Somehow it doesn't work with this code, I don't have any error's in the console.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Works for me. What kind of error do you get in the console ?

Comment: Please note that you're using two different clocks, one of the server and one on the client. They might not be in sync, or even worse, they probably are way out of sync... time zones, etc.

Comment: @B.Desai How to put this in ajax

Comment: If you are using JS to update the clock then you obviously don't need AJAX to get the clock from the server (PHP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
href="?update=true"
```

With

```
href="#"
```

The previous line makes your browser initiate a GET request, which you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

> - You can achieve your need at multi ways, below added the one way with your code.
> - you added `event.preventDefault();` so click event prevented.
> - or you can remove href link as per `BeetleJuice` suggest.

**Html**

```
<p class="card-text" id="updateAssignment">
    <span>Last update: <?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s')?></span>
    <a href="?update=true"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>Sync Date</a>
    </p>
```

**Scripts**

```
$('#updateAssignment a').on('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var currentdate = new Date();
            var datetime = "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                + (currentdate.getMonth())  + "/"
                + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":"
                + currentdate.getSeconds();
            $('#updateAssignment span').text(datetime);
        });
```

[***DEMO***](https://jsfiddle.net/tc9L065o/)

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```js
$('#updateAssignment').click(function(){
  var currentdate = new Date();
  var datetime = "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                + (currentdate.getMonth())  + "/"
                + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":"
                + currentdate.getSeconds();
  $('#updateAssignment').text(datetime);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="card-text" id="updateAssignment">Last update: PHP_HERE <a href="?update=true"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
href="?update=true"
```

to

```
href="#null"
```

and

```
$(function() {
    $('#updateAssignment').on('click', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var currentdate = new Date();
      var datetime = "Last Sync: " + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                + (currentdate.getMonth())  + "/"
                + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":"
                + currentdate.getSeconds();
      $('#updateAssignment').text(datetime);
    });
});
```

Wrap it by `$(function() {`